# Outlook alerts user when an email contains certain words and warns before sending

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016

I would like to be alerted before I send an email if the email I am composing contains certain words.

Example: Dog, cat, mouse,

I would like to be alerted if I forgot to change any of the words listed.

How can the below code be modified to be used for multiple word lookup ?

```
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(Item.Body, "(Client Name)") Then
        If MsgBox("Are you sure to send this message?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Message Text Warning") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we couldn't achieve it through basic function in Outlook client, and for more information about script development, it's suggested to post your issue in [Outlook for developer forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=outlookdev).

Also, for the requirement of alert before you send the specific message, based on my research, I also find a related add-ins: [Outgoing Email Checker](https://www.ablebits.com/docs/outlook-outgoing-email-checker/) ,which could manage outgoing messages with rules, please kindly check it and hope that would be helpful to you.